# How to get a jclass in JNI from class residing in an OSGi bundle

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface, osgi

In C/C++ you need a `jclass` value in order to register native functions to a Java class with methods declared `native`.

Consider this Java class:

```
public class Native {
  public native int f(int i);
}
```

To register a native C/C++ function for `Native.f()` we need to call this on C++ side:

```
JNIEnv* env = ...;
jclass nativeClass = ...;

JNINativeMethod nativeMethod = {
  (char*) "f",
  (char*) "(I)I",
  (void*) Java_org_example_Native_f // The native C function
};

env->RegisterNatives(nativeClass, &nativeMethod, 1);
```

The problematic part is to get the `jclass` value if the class is not accessible from the default class loader. This not the case if the class `Native` resides in an OSGi bundle loaded inside an OSGi container (e.g. Equinox) running inside the JVM.

To get to the class, I use a Java function to return the `Class<?>` instance of my class:

```
public class Helper {
  public static Class<?> getNativeClass() {
    // Find bundle from system bundle context.
    Bundle bundle = ... // details left out.

    return bundle.loadClass("org.example.Native");
  }
}
```

This function resides in a class outside the OSGi container. Calling this function from the C++ side using JNI gives us a `jobject` which is an instance of `java.lang.Class<>`.

```
// Load the `Helper` class.
jclass helperClass = env->FindClass("org.example.Helper");

// Get the method `Helper.getNativeClass()`.
jmethodId mid = env->GetStaticMethodID(helperClass,
                                       "getNativeClass",
                                       "()Ljava/lang/Class;");

// Call `Helper.getNativeClass()`.
jobject nativeClassInstance = env->CallStaticObjectMethod(helperClass, mid);
```

The problem is that we really need a 'jclass' value (not a `jobject` value). To get it, I instantiate an object of my `Native` class and get the `jclass` from that.

```
// This is the jclass for 'java.lang.Class<>'.
jclass classClass = env->GetObjectClass(nativeClassInstance);

// Now get the method id for function 'newInstance()'
jmethodId newInstanceMid = env->GetMethodID(helperClass,
                                            "newInstance",
                                            "()Ljava/lang/Object;");

// Instantiate our 'Native' class calling 'Class<Native>.newInstance()'.
jobject nativeInstance = env->CallObjectMethod(classClass,
                                               nativeClassInstance,
                                               newInstanceMid);

// Now, I can get the desired 'jclass' of my 'Native' class.
jclass nativeClass = env->GetObjectClass(nativeInstance);
```

But this only works because I can instantiate my `Native` class.

Any ideas how to get the desired `jclass` without having to instantiate an object of the `Native` class?

Comment: I don't understand the question. If the class has native methods, just loading it in the normal course of Java execution should cause its System.loadLibrary() call in its static initialization method to be executed, which will register its own native functions automatically. Why are you doing this back to front?

Comment: @EJP because I have a statically linked C++ server (cross platform including Win32) in which I want to embed a JVM (and inside that JVM I need to run OSGi). In Win32 it is not a good idea to mix statically and dynamically linked C/C++ runtime libs so my native implementation needs to be statically linked to the C++ application.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to use the `jobject` of type `Class<Native>` that's returned by your helper method as a `jclass` by simply casting it:

```
jclass nativeClass = (jclass)nativeClassInstance;
```

Comment: Embarrassingly simple :-). I did not realise that `jclass` is simply a subclass of `jobject` – just like `jstring` is. I also tried to use `dynamic_cast<jclass>(...)` (after reading your reply) but realised that `jobject` and `jclass` are not polymorphic since there (for efficiency reasons, I guess) are no virtual methods, not even the destructor.

Answer (score 0):

There is an easier way to do this if you don't need your native code stubs to be defined in the bundle.

Put your native code inside a class that is in your JVM's classpath.
Use `org.osgi.framework.system.packages.extra=package.in.jvm` when launching the bundle. Now the package is available from your OSGi bundle and you can call your native functions after you have linked them.